# Why asp.net core project is crashing, when EFCore try to return data to controller from repository?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to fetch data from database by using EFCore in my asp.net core mvc application, but application crashes, when repository try to return data to controller.

Tools I am using Vs2017, MSSQL2017, Asp.net Core 2.2, EFCore2.2. I have made a repository which authenticate user from database. When I try to authenticate user through repository by sending username and password through controller, so application crashes.

Even though I can see while debugging that user is authenticated and repository fetching that user from database. But when repository try to return user to controller, so application crashes. It does not generate any kind Exception, but crashes as soon as repository try to return user.

But I can see some information in the output windows of Vs2017, which is as follows

"iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation"

Controller Code

public class LoginController : AppController
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

```
    public LoginController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {            
        return View(new LoginViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        loginViewModel.Password = EncryptionLibrary.EncryptText(loginViewModel.Password);

        var user = _userRepository.FindUser(loginViewModel.Username, loginViewModel.Password);
        if ( user!= null)
        {                
            this.CurrentSaleState.Login.Id = user.Id;
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "RegisterCompany");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Repository Code

public UserModel FindUser(string userName, string password)
        {

```
            using (IRepositoryContext context = _repositoryFactory.CreateContext())
            {
                var user = context.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == userName && u.Password == password);
                var userModel = _modelMapper.Map<User, UserModel>(user);
                return userModel;
            }

    }
```

I expect that after authenticating user should move to another page.

Comment: Returning `null` from the `Login` action is meaningless. The action is supposted to return a success or failure message. BTW encrypting passwords is a *VERY* bad security practice. So are password reminder messages.  There's a very good reason ASP.NET stopped offering password encryption and reminders 10+ years ago and *all* security guidelines warn against this. Use the built-in ASP.NET Identity provider. It already provides strong password hashing, password reset, 2FA and a lot more

Comment: Even if you decide that you do need to modify the built-in login pages, you can use their code as a guide that shows what each action should be return and what should be returned

Comment: You are right, but right now I am just doing for testing purpose. I will correct it later. but my problem is something else which I mentioned above.

Comment: No, the problem is precisely this - a `Login` action that doesn't return a result, that tries to do what it isn't supposed to do at all. Use the built-in provider *first*. See how it works, what it returns. Your custom classes should do the same. A `Login` form redirects to the original URL, it doesn't return `null`.

Comment: `Access violation` means the application tried to use an invalid address. Typically this means that a `NULL` was used as an address or something that points outside the process's memory space. And `Login` itself returns a `NULL`

Comment: Furthermore, you should add logging to your application and log any exceptions. Right now, your code allows any exceptions to terminate the application without any attempt at logging. *Both* of those concerns though, authentication and logging, are covered by the built-in templates. Why don't you try a tutorial that shows how ASP.NET Core works before trying to customize anything?

Comment: Change `return null` to `return View(loginViewModel)`.Besides, have you tried to run your VS2017 with administrator permission?

Comment: I have changed return null to return View(loginViewModel) and also ran vs2017 under administrative privileges, but it does not help. Problem is not with the view problem is with this line  "return userModel;" in the above code. I can see that repository is fetching data from database but when It try to return data to controller. so application craches on "return userModel" line. Problem is system is not generating any exception or error. It just crache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably too late to the party but just for whoever wanders here.

I see you're using a mapper.

In my case this exact situation was caused by a StackOverflowException due to erroneous mapping.